# PhpStorm compile SCSS to remote host

Tags: sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

Does anybody know how to compile scss to remote host?
I have a scss file on a remote host which doesn't compile after save.

I can do that locally (it works using file watcher) but the problem is with the remote host -- I don't want to download the file and work on it and re-upload it on every save..

This is my current File Watcher config:

[image: File watcher configuration screenshot]

Comment: It does not work like that. Remote editing is mean for simple operations -- quite a lot of functionality gets lost if you use it (instead of downloading the file and editing it locally as part of the project). You should just download and edit it locally and configure your deployment to upload your changes on save (including external changes -- which is done by File Watcher).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne . I will do it like that. Also here is some tut from PhpStorm on Syncing local files with remote ones: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm